# CTAS query in Oracle for Index Organized tables

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to write a CTAS (create table as select ...) query in Oracle to create Index Organized tables ?

Have looked on the net and tried a few versions of the CTAS, but unable to find a working sample/quide query.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?
in the docs for 11g there's an example given for that https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#ADMIN11685 Does this answer your need?

Comment: I have no problem with it at all.  Perhaps you should edit your post to include the actual ddl of your source IOT, and the sql and result of your CTAS.

Comment: `CTAS` means *create table as select* (not with DDL only which is trival and linked by @micklesh). The tricky part is to define the `PRIMARY KEY` which is required for `organization index` but can't be done as the column definition part is not allowed.

Comment: as per the doc the syntax would be CREATE TABLE admin_iot3(i PRIMARY KEY, j, k, l) 
     ORGANIZATION INDEX 
     PARALLEL
     AS SELECT * FROM hr.jobs;
haven't tried it myself though

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.
Example, based on the [JOB_HISTORY table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/comsc/schema-diagrams.html#GUID-01BFEF14-C6BD-42CD-8558-DDD214DB3AE0):

**table JOB_HISTORY**

```
SQL> select * from hr.job_history ;
  EMPLOYEE_ID START_DATE   END_DATE    JOB_ID         DEPARTMENT_ID 
          102 13-JAN-93    24-JUL-98   IT_PROG                   60 
          101 21-SEP-89    27-OCT-93   AC_ACCOUNT               110 
          101 28-OCT-93    15-MAR-97   AC_MGR                   110 
          201 17-FEB-96    19-DEC-99   MK_REP                    20 
          114 24-MAR-98    31-DEC-99   ST_CLERK                  50 
          122 01-JAN-99    31-DEC-99   ST_CLERK                  50 
          200 17-SEP-87    17-JUN-93   AD_ASST                   90 
          176 24-MAR-98    31-DEC-98   SA_REP                    80 
          176 01-JAN-99    31-DEC-99   SA_MAN                    80 
          200 01-JUL-94    31-DEC-98   AC_ACCOUNT                90
```

**Query (for generating sample data)**

```
-- every employee must do every job (only for a day at a time ...)
select E.employee_id, J.job_id
, sysdate - ( row_number() over ( order by E.employee_id, J.job_id )  ) dt
from (
  select unique employee_id from hr.job_history
) E cross join (
  select unique job_id from hr.job_history
) J ;

--
  EMPLOYEE_ID JOB_ID       DT          
          101 AC_ACCOUNT   10-FEB-20   
          101 AC_MGR       09-FEB-20   
          101 AD_ASST      08-FEB-20   
          101 IT_PROG      07-FEB-20   
          101 MK_REP       06-FEB-20   
          101 SA_MAN       05-FEB-20   
          101 SA_REP       04-FEB-20   
          101 ST_CLERK     03-FEB-20   
          102 AC_ACCOUNT   02-FEB-20   
          102 AC_MGR       01-FEB-20   
...   
          200 ST_CLERK     25-DEC-19   
          201 AC_ACCOUNT   24-DEC-19   
          201 AC_MGR       23-DEC-19   
          201 AD_ASST      22-DEC-19   
          201 IT_PROG      21-DEC-19   
          201 MK_REP       20-DEC-19   
          201 SA_MAN       19-DEC-19   
          201 SA_REP       18-DEC-19   
          201 ST_CLERK     17-DEC-19   
--56 rows selected.
```

**CTAS**

```
-- heap organized table
create table heap_empjobs (
  employee_id, job_id, dt
, constraint heap_empjobs_pk primary key( employee_id, job_id, dt )
) 
as
select E.employee_id, J.job_id
, sysdate - ( row_number() over ( order by E.employee_id, J.job_id )  ) dt
from (
  select unique employee_id from hr.job_history
) E cross join (
  select unique job_id from hr.job_history
) J 
;
-- Table created.

-- index organized table
create table iot_empjobs (
  employee_id, job_id, dt
, constraint iot_pk primary key( employee_id, job_id, dt ) -- also works without naming the constraint
) 
organization index
as
select E.employee_id, J.job_id
, sysdate - ( row_number() over ( order by E.employee_id, J.job_id )  ) dt
from (
  select unique employee_id from hr.job_history
) E cross join (
  select unique job_id from hr.job_history
) J
;
-- Table created.
```

**Checks**

```
select count(*) from heap_empjobs ;
  COUNT(*) 
        56 

select count(*) from iot_empjobs ;
  COUNT(*) 
        56 


select table_name, nvl( to_char( num_rows ), 'no rows!' ) rowcount
from user_tables 
where table_name in ('HEAP_EMPJOBS', 'IOT_EMPJOBS') ;

TABLE_NAME     ROWCOUNT   
HEAP_EMPJOBS   56         
IOT_EMPJOBS    no rows!
```

Tested with Oracle 18c and 11g (see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=247997de32c1ea1fb09445751c511c67)).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed script :)